# How to check whether \Drupal\Core\Archiver\Zip::extract() succeeded?

Tags: 8

I called [\Drupal\Core\Archiver\Zip::extract()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Archiver!Zip.php/class/Zip/) to extract files from an archive. How can I tell whether extraction was successful?

Comment: thats a good question because the `Zip` class's `extractTo()` returns TRUE or FALSE on success. But the Drupal wrapper class simply does nothing with the return value and returns `$this` .... http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Drupal [Zip](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Archiver%21Zip.php/class/Zip/8.4.x) class is just a wrapper around the PHP [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class.

As @tenken already mentioned the wrapper just returns itself:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function extract($path, array $files = []) {
    if ($files) {
      $this->zip->extractTo($path, $files);
    }
    else {
      $this->zip->extractTo($path);
    }

    return $this;
  }
```

I guess that your best option is to retrieve the [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) object itself via the `getArchive()` method of the [Zip](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Archiver%21Zip.php/class/Zip/8.4.x) class. On the [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class call the `extractTo()` method and check its output (TRUE or FALSE).

I am currently working on a rewrite of the archiver classes to use [PharData](http://php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php): https://www.drupal.org/node/2891871. The [PharData](http://php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php) class throws exceptions on failure. If this issue is done and the patch lands you are able to catch exceptions to check if the archive operations were successful.